# Magento 2 how can i add block in core layout

Tags: magento2, layout

I am trying to load my block and template in my custom layout file as per below script but it's not rendering

Core Layout sales_order_create_index.xml :-

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="admin.scope.col.wrap" htmlClass="admin__old" /> <!-- ToDo UI: remove this wrapper with old styles removal. The class name "admin__old" is for tests only, we shouldn't use it in any way -->

    <referenceBlock name="page.title">
        <action method="setTitleId">
            <argument translate="false" name="id" xsi:type="string">order-header</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="optional_zip_countries" as="optional_zip_countries" template="Magento_Directory::js/optional_zip_countries.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Composite\Configure" name="after.body.start.product_composite_configure" template="Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/composite/configure.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="js">
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/js.phtml" name="create"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create" name="order_content">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/form.phtml" name="order_create_form" as="form">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Messages" name="message"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Customer" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/abstract.phtml" name="customer.grid.container"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Store" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/abstract.phtml" name="store">
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Store\Select" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/store/select.phtml" name="select"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Data" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/data.phtml" name="data">
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Sidebar" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/sidebar.phtml" name="sidebar">
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Sidebar\Cart" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/sidebar/items.phtml" name="cart"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Sidebar\Wishlist" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/sidebar/items.phtml" name="wishlist"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Sidebar\Reorder" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/sidebar/items.phtml" name="reorder"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Sidebar\Viewed" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/sidebar/items.phtml" name="viewed"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Sidebar\Compared" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/sidebar/items.phtml" name="compared"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Sidebar\Pcompared" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/sidebar/items.phtml" name="pcompared"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Sidebar\Pviewed" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/sidebar/items.phtml" name="pviewed"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/form/account.phtml" name="form_account"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Address" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/form/address.phtml" name="shipping_address"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Billing\Address" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/form/address.phtml" name="billing_address"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Method" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/abstract.phtml" name="shipping_method">
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Shipping\Method\Form" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml" name="order_create_shipping_form" as="form"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Billing\Method" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/abstract.phtml" name="billing_method">
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Billing\Method\Form" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/billing/method/form.phtml" name="order_create_billing_form" as="form"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Newsletter" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/abstract.phtml" name="newsletter">
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Newsletter\Form" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/newsletter/form.phtml" name="order_create_newsletter_form" as="form"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/abstract.phtml" name="search">
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" name="search_grid" as="grid"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Items" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/items.phtml" name="items">
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Items\Grid" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/items/grid.phtml" name="items_grid">
                            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Coupons" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/coupons/form.phtml" name="coupons">
                                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Coupons\Form" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/coupons/form.phtml" name="order_create_coupons_form" as="form"/>
                            </block>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Comment" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/comment.phtml" name="comment"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/totals.phtml" name="totals"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="gift_options" template="Magento_Sales::order/giftoptions.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Giftmessage" template="Magento_Sales::order/create/giftmessage.phtml" name="giftmessage"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="order_item_extra_info"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

My Custom layout sales_order_create_index.xml :-

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="admin.scope.col.wrap">
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="order_content">
                <block class="Vendor\BillingStep\Block\Adminhtml\Customform"  after="data.order_create_billing_form" template="Vendor_BillingStep::order/customform.phtml" name="custom_form"/>
            </referenceBlock>
       </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: On which place of create order you want to show the form?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code instead of your for the file **sales_order_create_index.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="billing_method">
            <block class="Vendor\BillingStep\Block\Adminhtml\Customform"  after="data.order_create_billing_form" template="Vendor_BillingStep::order/customform.phtml" name="custom_form"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's not displaying..@sukumar

Comment: Where did you place this xml?

Comment: I kept that file in Vendor/BillingStep/view/adminhtml/layout

Comment: Can you just add only text like 'Test form' and check its coming or not? It should come just after the payment methods section but only for create order form.

Comment: we are't able insert in side the "order_content" Block, i directly kept in core file..May i know why? it's not allowing

Comment: According to your requirement you asked you want to show the custom block just after the order_create_billing_form block. And my code insert the custom block without core files to the same block. Can you explain what do you exactly want? And exactly where you want to place the custom block?

Comment: Actually i kept your code in overrides xml file, but my custom template is not loading. i thought that if i add in code file it may be work, that the reason i added in core file directly but  my custom template is not loading. It's not accepting new name declaration (name="custom_form") inside the form block.
its allowing only ( name="customer.grid.container", ......,name="form_account" name="customer.grid.container", ......etc only what is available in form block)